# Capture screen recording with UITesting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any tool or service for **capturing screen-recording or screenshot with UITesting?**

I **do not** want snapshot testing from https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it in the scheme

[image]

First you need to remove checkmark in "Delete when each test succeeds" remove checkmark in "Delete when each test succeeds" in attachments section too

Then you can find the screenshots in test logs

[image]

You can also take screenshots of different components using `screenshot()`

```
let screenShot = emailTextField.screenshot()
let emailScreenAttachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenShot)
emailScreenAttachment.name = "screnshot of email textField"
emailScreenAttachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
add(emailScreenAttachment)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where are these screenshot stored?
Also, recording is also possible ?

Comment: @nirav my answer was updated please let me know, as far as I know you can only take screenshots no recording